# decimal format calss issue

Tags: java, decimalformat

I was making a simple program and when I compile it here is what I get "Incompatible types: string cannot be converted to a double" 
I checked my code many times and could not find what was wrong.
 here is my code:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class practice
{
public static void main(String []args)
{
double num1, num2, numAns;
String inputNum1, inputNum2;

DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");

inputNum1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the first number!");
num1 = Double.parseDouble(inputNum1);
num1 = formatter.format(num1);

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, num1);

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`num1` is a `double`, you can't assign a `String` to it. But you don't need to. You can do something like

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, formatter.format(num1));
```

**or** like

```
String formatted = formatter.format(num1);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, formatted);
```

Comment: so, `DecimalFormat` can only assing a formatted double to a string?

Comment: [`NumberFormat.format(double)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#format%28double%29) (which is the interface method you are calling) returns a `String`.